# Process exit code 0xC0000135 while running Qt hello world

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, clion

Here is my `main.cpp` code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hello, world!");
    button.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

Running it in CLion IDE (latest version) gives me the following error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(simple_interpreter)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

if (WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
endif ()
set(ENV{PATH} "C:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/bin") # As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739411
set(Qt5_DIR "C:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/Qt5")
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui)

add_executable(simple_interpreter main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(simple_interpreter Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui)
```

Comment: `set(ENV{PATH} "C:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/bin")` I am not sure that this works. You may just want to try setting the PATH environment variable in windows and rebooting or logout / login. It may just set the environment variable for the configure / generate stage but not change it for the IDE which is the parent process.

Comment: do an "Exec" instead of a "show"

Comment: Thanks! Adding it to the PATH directly from OS instead of CMakeLists.txt, then closing and re-opening the IDE fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) for `set(ENV ...)`:

> This command affects only the current CMake process, not the process from which CMake was called, nor the system environment at large, nor the environment of subsequent build or test processes.

So, this does **not** set the `PATH` environment variable within your CLion environment. You should instead try appending the path `C:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/bin` to the `Path` variable in your System Environment Variables on your Windows machine. Then, be sure to restart CLion, so the `Path` variable update is applied.